# how to insert content in menu of slidebar in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

**I have searched lot but couldn't find the solution
**
i have added a sidebar in my portal webpage and i want to added content in the option so when i click on it .It will display in right side of the page and i want to do it without passing hyperlink because i don't want to write the code of sidebar in all the pages and want to fix sidebar for all pages .Please provide me the solution!

[screen shot of mypage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPTMt.png)
i have to added a content in all the sub-menu